# Passing arrays to functions in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

I have a procedure which accepts arrays. Thus I can pass an array like :

```
Public Sub MySub (Something as String, ByRef Arr() as Variant)
  'Stuff
End Sub


Public Sub Test()

   Dim Columns() As Variant
   Columns = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

   MySub "sth", Columns

End Sub
```

The problem is that when I want to do it inline like

```
MySub "sth", Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

or

```
MySub "sth", Cvar(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

I get a compile error saying that type mismatch: Array or user defined type expected.

How can I pass an inline array to function?

Comment: The `Array()` function does not return an array of Variant(), but a Variant of subtype Array, that is why you are getting an type mismatch error.

Answer (score 4):

Change the array parameter from an array of variants to just a variant

```
Public Sub MySub(Something As String, ByRef Arr As Variant)
  'Stuff
End Sub


Public Sub Test()

   Dim Columns() As Variant
   Columns = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

   MySub "sth", Columns
   MySub "sth", Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
   'both worked in my test
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I used Excel 2013 to run your VBA code and there's no type mismatch error.
For example with the sub:

```
Public Sub MySub(Something As String, ByRef Arr() As Variant)
    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
        Debug.Print Arr(i)
        Next i
    End
End Sub
```

I get the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, numbers printed out in the immediate window (Ctrl + G)

Comment: If you just copy his first code it will work, but if you inline the call to Array as he wrote, you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword `call` before the calling statement and put all the arguments within parenthesis like this:

```
call MySub ("sth", Cvar(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)))
```